# How to force RTL semantic on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, right-to-left

I'm trying to force my app to be RTL on app start.
Everything works fine on iOS 9, using:

```
if(version >= 9.0){
   [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
}
```

Now I'm testing it on iOS 8 and of course this method doesn't work.

Does anyone know the equivalent of the method that work for iOS 8?

Comment: Is this for testing or for production?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877140/how-can-i-set-localised-direction-within-applicationrtl-if-user-select-arabic

Comment: Hei Max, did you make it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for testing while in development then you can do this with an option in the Xcode run scheme...

[image]

This will override the RTL setting for the phone for the debug session.

Comment: thanks for your reply. im actually trying to force any production ver to go RTL, on app start (somewhere in AppDelegate). i got it going with the language, both ios 8 and 9. now i want app semantic to be RTL as well (when it reads the view constraints as RTL as well). ive done it for ios 9 as i post in my question but i cant find it for ios lower then this.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 8, you can use the UIApplication layout direction :

```
BOOL isRTL = [UIApplication sharedApplication].userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft;
```