# dropdown Autolayout in Arabic language in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, drop-down-menu, arabic

I have a dropdown which is working properly in english, but when the language changes to Arabic it doesn't show in the right position.

```swift
DropDown1.anchorView = self.ClassButton
```

[result with english language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTvaP.png)

[result with arabic language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkc79.png)

Comment: Do you have issue in  language or in dropdown position?

Comment: dropdown is working properly but with arabic language it does not show on proper position.u can see attachment

Comment: Do you know if this is related to the writing orientation? I'm just guessing here because I never worked with an app in Arabic. Maybe this works for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31877713/6361488

Answer (score 1):

```
if LanguageManager.shared.isRightToLeft {
    dropDown.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1))
    dropDown.customCellConfiguration = { (index: Index, item: String, cell: DropDownCell) -> Void in
        // Setup your custom UI components
        cell.optionLabel.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1))
    }
}
```