# LTR To RTL Using same xib in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, multilingual

I am stuck to one point i want to develop a app that support LTR and RTL both but i don't want to create two .xib for LTR and RTL.

So can any one provide me any method avalable fot LTR to RTL using same xib.

thank you in advance.

Comment: you mean without restarting the app after changing lanuage , i mean in same language context ?

Comment: check my answer here: full background (iOS versions, cases, etc..) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877140/how-can-i-set-localised-direction-within-applicationrtl-if-user-select-arabic/31877713#31877713

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes When user select language from app i want to change all UI to RTL and i will change all text.

Mean if i have button on left bottom and i set RTL language than that button should set to Right bottom exact mirror design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by changing the semantics

```
   self.anyView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

OR

```
   self.anyView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

In objective-c

```
 self.anyView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight;
```

Or

```
 self.anyView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;
```

see also this demo : [RTLDemo](https://github.com/ShKhan9/RTLDemo)

Comment: see edit , also don't forget to make constraints leading and trailing instead of right / left so RTL can work

Comment: @hardikvyas wait for a demo

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create 2 xib files in order to get LTR and RTL to work.

Basically you need to:

1. set leading **and** trailing constraints
2. If iPhone language is RTL leading will now act as trailing and trailing will act as leading (thus there is no need to create 2 xib files and your view element will be flipped)
3. In some cases you may want to [force RTL/LTR](https://evgenii.com/blog/supporting-right-to-left-languages-in-ios-with-swift/) images using [imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624140-imageflippedforrighttoleftlayout?language=objc):

   ```
   image = [image imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection];
   ```

   while checking current language using:

   ```
   BOOL isLeftToRight = [UIView userInterfaceLayoutDirectionForSemanticContentAttribute:[[self view] semanticContentAttribute]] == UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight;
   ```
4. Remember that each UIView has [semanticContentAttribute](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622461-semanticcontentattribute?language=objc) that can be set to force RTL [UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisemanticcontentattribute?language=objc). i.e:

   ```
   [view setSemanticContentAttribute: UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
   ```
5. When using textFields please use the below alignment so each RTL/LTR will work as it should be:

   [image]

Comment: i want it in objective c

Comment: Updated to objc

Comment: Thanks for your answer. your given solution works very fine for me thank you again....

Comment: You can reaccept this answer if you think it solved your issue - the accepted answer is the answer that suits your needs the best.

Comment: your solution is works for me but as Above ans is as perfect as i want so i have accepted above answer. but as your answer is also good so i have upvote your answer and comment on it so other developer can also get to know that this answer is also works.

Answer (score 0):

below are a few of my methods.

- first of all, verify if the layout direction (you could create a macro for this)

  [UIApplication sharedApplication].userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft
- use IBOutlet for NSLayoutConstraint and set constant/priority to shift your UI elements
- for labels use `NSTextAlignmentNatural` for left alignment in LTR and for RTL will take care the system. Else you have to set them by yourself the text alignment
- for some relevant images you have to flip them horizontally
- for any kind of drawings (in drawRect or layers) you should pay attention

These are important for me, but there are more. Just be creative